# Seek query to change a text parent-child relationship into an integer parent-child relationship

Tags: tree

What is the query against table a that returns the result below?

```
with a as  ( values
(1,'a023C000002yyrBQAQ',''),
(2,'a023C000002yy0SQAQ','a023C000002yyrBQAQ'),
(3,'a023C000002yy0WQAQ','a023C000002yyrBQAQ'),
(4,'a023C000002yx3OQAQ','a023C000002yyrBQAQ'),
(5,'a023C000002yzrjQAA','a023C000002yyrBQAQ'),
(6,'a023C000002z0c9QAA','a023C000002yyrBQAQ'),
(7,'a023C000002z0XEQAY','a023C000002yyrBQAQ'),
(8,'a023C000002yx3QQAQ','a023C000002z0c9QAA'),
(9,'a023C000002yx4KQAQ','a023C000002yy0SQAQ'),
(10,'a023C000002yx4MQAQ','a023C000002z0XEQAY'),
(11,'a023C000002yx4tQAA','a023C000002yx3OQAQ'),
(12,'a023C000002yxRhQAI','a023C000002yy0WQAQ'),
(13,'a023C000002yyrqQAA','a023C000002yzrjQAA'),
(14,'a023C000002yyY2QAI','a023C000002yy0SQAQ'),
(15,'a023C000002yyY5QAI','a023C000002z0XEQAY'),
(16,'a023C000002yyY8QAI','a023C000002z0c9QAA'),
(17,'a023C000002yyYaQAI','a023C000002yy0WQAQ')
) select * from a
```

Result:

```
values (
(1,0),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,1),
(6,1),
(7,1),
(8,6),
(9,2),
(10,7),
(11,2),
(12,3),
(13,5),
(14,2),
(15,7),
(16,6),
(17,3)
)
```

Comment: It is probably a pretty simple self-join; have you tried it?

Comment: Table 'a' is a sample. And for the sample, good thinking - I could do a join.   The actual table I have has more than 1800 rows. And in different DEV environments the values are different (so I can't use hard coded values).

Comment: Unfortunately your question is unclear and lacking a lot of information that could help us help you. Please provide more information such as table definition and some sample data in it and sample results you expect. Also please explain the meaning of your results, as there's no clear correlation between your query and the example results you provided.

Comment: good point. Thanks I'll make the write-up clearer tomorrow morning. For now though. Table 'a' is the table definition. The column on the left is the parent column while the column on the right is the child. And I'm looking for a query which changes the parent child relationship from text into integer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an [Adjacency List](https://www.databasestar.com/hierarchical-data-sql/#C2), a way to express a tree in a table. Rather than use a numeric identifier to enumerate the nodes, your tree uses a unique string. The logic is the same.

Mustaccio is on the right track to answer your question: Use a left self-join to add the parent "name" to the child's row. You did not give a database engine and a table definition so I can't adapt it to your situation, but the pattern looks like this (taken from the link):

```
SELECT e.id, e.first_name, e.role, e.manager_id, m.first_name
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee m ON e.manager_id = m.id;
```

In your data, `first_name` is the first column, `id` is the second, and `manager_id` is the third.

You can also use a correlated subquery to look up the parent, but the join is more performant with large data sets.

Comment: The left join tip in your answer was spot on. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't post the left join statement and answer my question. My question was deemed not to meet stackexchange standards and my account deactivated. Thanks. I got it though.